# Force English keyboard on textfields

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I am developing an app that supports English and Arabic languages without problem. To sign up, I need the user to always have the keyboard in English even though he has it in Arabic, otherwise our backend won't understand the arabic characters. How can I enforce that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this should work for you...

Specifies a keyboard that displays standard ASCII characters.

```
textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
```

Hope it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
```

I just tried it on a simulator with Arabic as the language, and that only has the Arabic keyboard.